# what concepts do people use to link between pages in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I am a new AngularJS developer and I know some concepts that angularjs use like SPA and Components. I am really confused about the concept of redirecting to another pages in any Angular app. I want to know what's the best solution for redirect users through the app pages.

So I've some questions to ask.

1. Can I use HTML ahref tags normally as it's an html application or Should I use SPA concept to allow the user to go to other pages?
2. Do I have to create a new component for each Page I create in my Angular application ?

Comment: angular router.

Comment: Are you talking about **[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)** or **[Angular](https://angular.io/)** ? Because that are two totally different things.

Comment: I am talking about AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1st part, "Can I use HTML ahref tags normally as it's an html application or Should I use SPA concept to allow the user to go to other pages?" - You should not use ahref and leverage the SPA feature of AngularJS.

For 2nd part - **No**. Think component as a reusable entity. You might want to use same component on multiple pages. Suppose you want to display card layout on multiple pages, than create it as component or if you want to implement infinite scroll feature on multiple pages of your application than create it as component.

And one of the approach for routing could be - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help